# BBC EMP (Embedded Media Player) "Content appears not to be working..."

Tags: javascript, streaming

### Background

We have been embedding the EMP (http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/help/7277283.stm) in a quadrant on our bespoke MI wall boards for some months successfully. The code uses a div to host an iframe:

```
   <div id="emp1" class="player" style="float: left; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <p>In order to see this content you need to have both <a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/webwise/askbruce/articles/browse/java_1.shtml" title="BBC Webwise article about enabling javascript">Javascript</a> enabled and <a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/webwise/askbruce/articles/download/howdoidownloadflashplayer_1.shtml" title="BBC Webwise article about downloading">Flash</a> installed. Visit <a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/webwise/">BBC&nbsp;Webwise</a> for full instructions</p>
</div>
```

And then a bunch of javascript to populate it:

```
function updateEmp(widthEmp, heightEmp) {
    width = widthEmp;
    height = heightEmp;
    $('bbc_emp_embed_emp1').morph({ width: widthEmp + 'px', height: heightEmp + 'px' });
}

function reload(url, title) {
    var emp = new embeddedMedia.Player();
    emp.setWidth("100%");
    emp.setHeight("100%");
    emp.setDomId("emp1");
    emp.quality = "low";
    emp.set("config_settings_autoPlay", "true");
    emp.setPlaylist('http://www.bbc.co.uk/emp/simulcast/bbc_news24.xml');
    emp.setConfig('http://www.bbc.co.uk/emp/simulcast/config_bbc_news24.xml');
    emp.write();
}
```

### The problem

Last week the EMP was either retired or has broken. Check out the below link for what we get when we try and access the EMP (just the text "This content doesn't seem to be working. Try again later." :

http://www.bbc.co.uk/emp/player.swf

I have contacted the beeb and have had no response as yet. Is there another way to embed the bbc other than a nasty iframe surrounded by a div with overflow hidden?

Comment: Your very last question is off-topic because you're asking for a recommendation.

Comment: Fair, I have removed the off-topic element.